# ggplot2 - group aesthetic not working as expected am I missing something?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a line graph with multiple lines (grouped by a categorical value - factor) and based on what I have done in the past and what I can find online here the easiest way to do this is by assigning the categorical value to the group aesthetic - but this isn't working for me I am only getting one line on the line graph. I am 100% sure I am doing something super silly but I can't for the life of me work it out. Thanks in advance :)

```
#dummy data for example
  test <- data.frame(x = sample(seq(as.Date('2015/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 20),
                      y = sample(10:300, 10),
                      Origin_Station = as.factor(rep(1, 10)),
                      Neighbour_station = as.factor(rep(1:5, each = 20)))
  #plot - what I want to see is a line for each of the 5 Neighbour_station categories (1:5) but what I get is just one line
  ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y, group = Neighbour_station))+
    geom_line()
```

I have also tried this:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y, group = factor(Neighbour_station), colour = Neighbour_station))+
    geom_line()
```

Comment: Your example x- and y-values are the same for each group, so the lines are just overlayed on top of one another.

Comment: Thank you I think I have merged incorrectly in my actual data set resulting in the same scenario outlined in the test/dummy data in the post - creating the repeated values per group. Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Rhetta also from Aus here, big ups Australian useRs:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test, aes(x = x, y = y, group = Neighbour_station, colour = Neighbour_station))+
      geom_line()
```

Note the reason you can't see the distinct lines is because your data is exactly the same for each factor level (Neighbour_station 1:5).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I knew I was doing something silly - I am pretty sure the merge I did prior to this plot is causing the issue with the repeated data per factor group.